# Using gson views with Grails and returning a null

Tags: grails, gson

I have the following Service:

```
def getSectorByName(String sectorName) {

    Sector theSector = Sector.where {
        name == sectorName
    }.get()

    return theSector
}
```

My Controller:

```
def getSector(String sectorName) {
    def theSector = sectorDataService.getSectorByName(sectorName)

    respond theSector
}
```

My gson view called getSector:

```
import application.Sector

model {

    Sector theSector
}

json {
    theSector g.render(theSector)
}
```

This is giving me the following result:

```
{"theSector":null}
```

When debugging the application I can see theSector does contain a Sector however this does not get passed to view.

Comment: Try to change json closure to "json g.render(theSector)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not giving a name to the sector object, the default naming convention is to use the "propertyName" of the class

Your view should be:

```
import application.Sector

model {

    Sector sector
}

json {
    theSector g.render(sector)
}
```

See the section in the documentation on debugging views to prevent further issues like this: http://views.grails.org/latest/#_debugging_views